# Git LFS doesn't track .gitattribtes on subfolders

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-lfs

I have like 9Gbs of folders and files for Git LFS to track. I specifically specified Git LFS to track those files with their own individual `.gitattributes` on their respective directories.

Uploaded (to Bitbucket) only had 2Gbs.

Do I have to put just only one `.gitattributes` file on the root directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `folder/*` to track a specific directory or `folder/**/*` to track the whole directory tree. Git LFS will automatically create a `.gitattributes` for you in the root of your repository.